# empty array should be a link

Tags: php, arrays

i have this assignment from school that i need to make but i'm getting stuck...
i need to make a script and it should get an image with the good link but i'm getting only an empty array. please help me make this better!
this is the code:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $url = "http://www.asaphshop.nl/epages/asaphnl.sf/nl_NL/?ObjectPath=/Shops/asaphnl/Products/80203122";
    $htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
    $pattern = '#class="noscript">.*(<img.*>).*</div>#isU';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches);
    //print_r ($matches);
    $image = ($matches[0]);
    print_r ($image);
    ?>
```

this is a part of the imagecode:

```
<div id="ProductImages" class="noscript">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg">
          <img
           itemprop="image"
           alt="Jesus Remember Me - Taize Songs (2CD)"
           src="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
           data-src-xs="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
           data-src-s="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_s.jpg"

           data-src-m="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_m.jpg"

           data-src-l="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg"
         />
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

the code of data-src-l should be in the back of https://www.asaphshop.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had used a debugger you would find out that you do not in fact get an empty array but an array containing an array with one value under the `['0']` key, which is this:

```
""class=\"noscript\">\n    <ul>\n  \n      \n        \n        \n          \n        \n        \n          \n        \n      \n      <li>\n        <a href=\"/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg\">\n          <img\n           itemprop=\"image\"\n           alt=\"Jesus Remember Me - Taize Songs (2CD)\"\n           src=\"/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg\"\n           data-src-xs=\"/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg\"\n           data-src-s=\"/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_s.jpg\"\n           \n           data-src-m=\"/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_m.jpg\"\n           \n           data-src-l=\"/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg\"\n         />\n        </a>\n      </li>\n  \n  \n    </ul>\n  </div>""
```

And as you can probably tell, something is wrong with your regex `$pattern`. Parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea anyway. What exactly are you trying to achieve? And also, is this the 5th time you're asking the same question here?

UPDATE:

If you need to get the images use this regex: `<img\s[^>]*?src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?>`. With it you will capture the value in the `src` tag of all images on the page and then you can use them to create your own image tags. Like so:

```
$htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
$pattern = "/<img\s[^>]*?src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches);
```

The `$matches[0]` array contains all the image tags and there are actually 16 of them. The `$matches[1]` array contains all the values in the `src` attributes of the images. You can use whichever you want.

Comment: Thanks! But still... I don't come any further with this... can you be more specific about the code? And it's an assignment for school. and what i'm trying to achieve is that i need to make a script what get info from a site named asaphshop.nl. I already got the basic info like title and authors and stuff. I did that with reading out an csv file. But now i need to do the image and description and the language. I need to do it with regular expressions. And it's not the 5th time i'm asking the same question. But if you think that i'm sorry.

Comment: @bananaman So you wish to get the image from the page using regex, is that right?

Comment: yes but it needs to be compatible for multiple pictures, because i need to put it later in the database.

Comment: @bananaman Check my answer update and see if the solution works for you.

Comment: thanks! but where do i put this piece?

Comment: @bananaman Check my answer again.

Comment: now it gives a few lines of images, it searches in the site so that's right. but now i need to get the imagelinks itself. it's trying to search in my localhost, but they can't find anything ofcourse. how do i solve this

Comment: @bananaman I'm not sure what you're asking here. The imagelinks aka the `src` of all images are in the `$matches[1]` array and the image tags in the `$matches[0]` array as per my code.